# Using JPA table-per-subclass inheritance with one-to-many relation

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa, one-to-many

I have the following scenario -

```
Table campaign_detail (
    campaign_detail_id (PK),
    campaign_detail_caption,
    campaign_detail_description,
    campaign_detail_type (DISCRIMINATOR)
)

Table campaign_price_detail (
    campaign_detail_id (PK) REFERENCES (campaign_detail), // ONE_TO_ONE with campaign_detail
    campaign_price_amount,
    campaign_price_URL
)

Table campaign_deal_detail (
    deal_id (PK)
    campaign_detail_id REFERENCES (campaign_detail), // MAN_TO_ONE with campaign_detail
    campaign_deal_code,
    campaign_deal_period
)
```

The Campaign has many detail information which can be grouped together as entities by themselves, say campaign_price, campaign_deal, campaign_contact, campaign_retailers etc (there are 9 in all). 
These groups have some common properties which are in the campaign_detail table.

I would like to use the table-per-subclass inheritance with campaign_detail and all its sub tables.

However I have one issue, which I am not sure how to handle. 
Most of the sub-tables, are related by a one-to-one relation with the campaign_detail table. So far so good. But some (3 out of 9) are related by many-to-one relation with the campaign_detail. For e.g, one campaign_detail could have to multiple deals, or multiple retailers.

So how do I use table-per-subclass inheritance JPA annotations for modelling these classes. All the examples I have seen so far consider only 1-to-1 relationships only.

I am using hibernate 4.1.4 Final.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Inheritance is used to model an *is a* relationship: A Car *is a* Vehicle. A Banana *is a* Fruit.

So this relationship doesn't make sense if you have one campaign detail, and several deals.  This is a composition relationship, where one campaign detail *has* several deals.

Comment: Thanks for your help. From a pure Object stand-point, I don't understand why this should not be possible - may be I am missing something. Let me take your example - Banana _is_ a Fruit and so is apple. Now let's say a bag of fruits can contain only one apple but any number of bananas. In that scenario, yes, I have multiple bananas but each banana is still a Fruit, isn't it. When I am dealing with the Fruit Bag, I would still like to deal with its contents as 'Fruit' in some context and 'Banana' in some other. Not being able to map it in JPA may be a limitation of the implementation ?

Comment: If we take your analogy, you're asking how to make Banana and Apple subclasses of FruitBasket. This makes no sense. Of course you may define a base entity for campaign_price, campaign_deal, campaign_contact, etc. But this base entity must not be CampaignDetail. Maybe I have not understood what you are asking. If so, please clarify.

Comment: No exactly, not subclasses of FruitBasket, but Fruit. I think a more appropriate analogy would be if I were to make "Bunch of Bananas" or "Bunch of Grapes" subclasses of Fruit. So yes, I have realized what I am asking for is not possible. While at the DB / Query semantics will work, Object inheritance will not work. Thanks for helping me see the problem.

Comment: To add to the discussion, the solution is to have an intermediate table to handle the inheritance, i.e., a table for a bunch of fruit. This table object will inherit from fruit and be a composition of bananas or grapes (you will need one table per each). This is not a limitation in JPA, you're trying to enforce an additional logical constraint so you need one more layer of abstraction.